# About the pullback of a $1$-form

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Suppose $M$, $N$  are smooth manifolds, $f: M\to N$ is a smooth map. Let $X$ be a vector field on $N$, which is function that assigns to each $n\in N$ a vector $X_n\in T_n N$, and let $\omega$ be the smooth $1$-form on $N$ dual to that vector field: $\omega(n)(X_{n})=1$ whenever $X_{n}\in T_{n} N$. Now $f^\ast\omega$ is a smooth $1$-form on $M$ defined by $(f^\ast\omega)(m)(Y_m)=\omega(f(m))(f_\ast Y_m)$, where $Y_m\in T_mM$. Since $f_\ast Y_m\in T_{f(m)} N$, it follows from definition that $\omega(f(m))(f_\ast Y_m)=1$ and so $f^\ast \omega \equiv 1$, which is a $0$-form. But how can this be possible if $f^\ast\omega$ is supposed to be a $1$-form?

Comment: As written, it appears that $\omega$ is dual to the fixed vector field $X$, but then you seem to switch to saying that $\omega$ is dual to *all* forms $f_\ast Y$, not just the fixed vector field $X$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Where do I switch the assumption that $\omega$ is only dual to $X$? $f_\ast X_m \in T_{f(m)} N$, so it can be written as $X_{f(m)}$. (This is a bad notation, I should have denoted tangent vectors to $M$ by $Y$ with subscripts, I edited the question). Then I thought $\omega(f(m))(X_{f(m)})=1$ because $\omega(n)(X_n)$ holds for all $n\in N$. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of your confusion is as follows:

- You state that $\omega_n(X_n)=1$ for all $n\in N$.  This is for a particular (fixed) vector field $X$.  Here, you state that this is true whenever $X_n\in T_nN$, i.e., $n\in N$.
- Later, you state that $\omega_{f(m)}(f_\ast Y_m)=1$, and it seems that your reasoning is that this is true *because* $f_\ast Y_m\in T_{f(m)}N$.
- The problem with this reasoning is that the condition above is not that $X_n\in T_nN$ (this is automatic from the fact that $X$ is a vector field).  You would only be guaranteed to get $\omega_{f(m)}(f_\ast Y_m)=1$ if $f_\ast Y_m=X_{f(m)}$.  There is no reason for this to be true.

What appears to be the case is that you're using the condition $X_n\in T_nN$ as the definition for $\omega_n(X_n)=1$, in other words, $\omega_n(X_n)=1$ whenever $X_n$ is a vector, so $\omega$ is the constant function, which is not true.

Comment: Thank you. Your interpretation of my confusion is correct. I see why I was wrong. But what if $f_\ast$ was surjective at each point? Then we could choose $Y_m$ so that $f_\ast Y_m=X_{f(m)}$, and $f^\ast \omega$ would be equal to 1. Am I missing something again?

Comment: That would only be for a particular $Y$, not an arbitrary one.  So, you've got $f^\ast \omega(Y)=1$ for that *one* $Y$.

Comment: You'd likely need some additional data about $f$ to say much of anything (e.g., is $f$ an immersion or submersion?).  Consider the case where $f$ is the constant map?

Comment: It would be better to start a new question than to ask one in comments, but to answer your question, suppose that $m\in M$ and $f_\ast Y_m=X_{f(m)}$.  Then, $(f^\ast\omega)(Y_m)\not=0$.